# x axis duplicate values are added up on SSRS charts

Tags: sql, reporting-services, charts, report, scatter

Forgive my Ignorance. I am new to SSRS reporting.

My x axis on a scatter chart is simple ID value(s) and my Y axis is Price. The values in the table are as follows

```
ID  Price
1   1.47
1   1.52
1   1.46
2   1.40
2   1.44
2   1.38
```

When the chart is plotted value for 1 under y axis is sum of 1.47 + 1.52 + 1.46.  The same happens for 2 etc.

I would like individuals dots on the chart e.g 1.47 a dot, 1.52 a dot and 1.46 another dot and so on.

Thanks

Comment: Any help? If you need more information please comment.

Comment: Any solution to this yet? I am struggling with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Category Group to the Id of your result set.

[image]

Of course I'm guessing as you really need to provide a bit more information (like a screenshot of your chart?)

Comment: I do not think this is solution to @abeuwe problem - as far as I can tell from description, chart suppose to display data on X,Y coordinates as they are - without aggregations just plain plot of points.